# How do i filter images with jquery + CSS

Tags: jquery, image, list, filtering

So i have a list wich comes from a mysql table .
Example:[http://i.imgur.com/MPJSR.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9FNfG.png)

This list contains certain categories with IDs .
To get a link between the categories and the images. I gave every image the same className as the class in the list 
ex.

```
(e.g  <a href="#" class="1">Logo</a>  and <img class="1" src="#" />
```

What's the best way to write this in JQuery?

I started writing a bit of jQuery code, but soon noticed that it was rubbish.

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
  $(".1").click(function(event){
    $('img.2').addClass("white");        
    $('img.3').addClass("white");        
    $('img.4').addClass("white");
    $('img.5').addClass("white");     
    $('img.6').addClass("white");
    $('img.7').addClass("white");        
    $('img.8').addClass("white");        
    $('img.9').addClass("white");
    $('img.10').addClass("white");
    $('img.11').addClass("white");
    $('img.12').addClass("white");
    $('img.13').addClass("white");    
   });
});
```

So my question to you guys is ... what's the best way to handle this without writing 100 lines of ugly code .

Comment: What's the best way to write it for what? The question is a little ambiguous.

Comment: Forget the code you wrote and try to explain what you are attempting to achieve.  For example: "When a user clicks on a link I want all the images with the same class as the link to be given a new class called 'white'".

Comment: @Jrod what i'm trying to achieve is ... a user clicks a link , after the click the photo's within the same category of the link (ex. Logo) do not change but the other photo's change opacity.

Comment: @KrisTemmerman is there a class/id on the container of the links?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should do the trick if I correctly understand the question.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){    
      $("#category a").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var clicked_class = $(this).attr('class');

        $('img').each( function() {
            var image = $(this);

            if( image.hasClass( clicked_class ) ) {
                image.removeClass( 'white' );
            } else {
                image.addClass( 'white' );
            }

        });


       });
    });
</script>
```

First we add the click event to anchors within the `#category` div. When they are clicked we then grab the class of the clicked anchor and then use that class to compare against each of the images.  If the image shares that class we update it with the `white` class else we remove the `white` class incase a previous action added it.

Comment: Well it almost worked ... the thing is when you click a list item, the images that are not in the category have to receive the white class

Comment: This is the correct solution `    $(document).ready(function(){    
      $("#category a").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var clicked_class = $(this).attr('class');

        $('#center img').each( function() {
            var image = $(this);

            if( image.hasClass( clicked_class ) ) {
                image.removeClass( 'white' );
            } else {
                image.addClass( 'white' );
            }

        });


       });
    });
` A big thanks goes out to Jrod who solved this question ! thanks man !

Comment: @KrisTemmerman if it is correct please mark it as so.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can **add multiple classes** to every dom element and jquery will still properly find it.
You need to assign additional class to all your images, like `class="1 thumb_image` , `class="2 thumb_image` and then simply use [jquery not](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) selector: `$('.thumb_image:not("1")').addClass("white");`

Comment: That should be `:not(".1")`.

Comment: Ok i tested this method and it's exactly what i was looking for . On the other hand , this still makes me type the code 13 times wich is still pretty anoyinj

Comment: What do you mean 13 times?
All you need to type is the class in your img dom element.
This function goes only once.
This function should cover a class of images "thumb_image".

Comment: `$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".1").click(function(event){
  $('.thumb_image:not(".1")').fadeTo("slow",0.33);
 });
});` And the code of my image is '<img class="thumb_image 3"/>'